# jboss enterprise soa platform versions

Tags: jboss, soa, jboss-esb

There are 2 major(4.x.x and 5.x.x) versions of JBoss Enterprise SOA Platform. I got these information from an article on redhat site (https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/111773).

I do not see versions prior to 4.2.0 on the download page for SOA platfrom.

SOA platfrom Download page :
access.redhat.com/jbossnetwork/restricted/listSoftware.html?product=soaplatform&downloadType=distributions

In addtion to this, I have searched the press release page on redhat.com and it shows 4.2.0 as the first version.
http://www.redhat.com/about/news/press-archive/2008/2/jboss-soa

I would like to know why the JBoss Enterprise SOA Platform version is started from 4.2.0?

If there are any prior versions before 4.2.0, why they are not downloadable from redhat.com download page?

Comment: The links that you provided are for enterprise customers only which we cant access. You need to consult with Red Hat/JBoss support for this.

Comment: Yes. the SOA platfrom Download page is not available for all the customers. But You can see the version details in this article https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/111773

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18332990/1211000//U can login and download soa platform here